# Ant - Concat all files in directory from multiple ivy libs

Tags: ant, ivy

I use ANT and I want to concat same files from multiple ivy libs. Every file can contain multiple lines.

All I have yet is this:

```
<concat destfile="${src}/META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory">
    <restrict>
        <archives>
            <zips>
                <fileset refid="ivy.libs" />
            </zips>
        </archives>
        <name name="META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory" />
    </restrict>
</concat>
```

I use org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory as example filename, but I want to concat all files in META-INF/services directory. I do not want to write this block for every possible filename. It would be better to iterate and then use this block with vars in a loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: You do understand how the concat task works? It will join together the files contained in the ivy lib directory. I ask because it don't understand why you would want to do this.

Comment: I use some libs, that each provide the same file with some interface-name lines in it. The problem is, that each lib contains different interfaces and if I build my project, then there is just one interface-name line instead 2 or 4.

Thats why I want to concat all the files with the same filename to get all line from lib files.

Comment: That makes no sense to me, apologies.